# Can't find the archive-keyring on amazon instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apt, package-management

Im relatively new to this so please bear with me ..

Im running an amazon instance with ubuntu 11.10

and after performing

```
apt-get upgrade
```

everything with my package manager went haywire
if i try to perform **any** apt-get operations i get

```
Fetched 35.2 MB in 7s (4,399 kB/s)                                                                                                                                
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up apt (0.8.16~exp5ubuntu13.6) ...
ERROR: Can't find the archive-keyring
Is the ubuntu-keyring package installed?
dpkg: error processing apt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and after looking around and trying a bunch of stuff which includes :
 - performing a clean and update or clean and upgrade
 - taking a new sources.list altogether
 - adding the keyring again
 - and a whole bunch of other completely random stuff in the desperate attempt of a miracle

nothing worked ..

so any help will help me find ......no, come close a solution will be greatly appreciated  :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted at the end of this thread worked for me:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2129550

Basically find another clean ubuntu machine and copy the /usr/share/keyrings/* to ur current /usr/share/keyrings directory. I had no files in this directory when I was getting the error. Once I copied the files from another ubuntu install, apt-get started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 sudo apt-get clean

 sudo apt-get -f install ubuntu-keyring
```

Comment: tried .. did not work .. same thing for all apt-get operation ..

Comment: have you tried this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: There are a whole bunch of other dependencies so i would not like to perform any operations which involves something that can upset the setup seeing that i have already screwed something up :D

Comment: try this  apt-get -f install archive-keyring

Comment: nope .. still the same issue

Comment: I kind of have added a hot fix for this temporarily ,
in the dpkg/apt.postint i have commented the like
apt-key update as this was causing the issue .. Its not the right fix but for now i think ill keep it :)